# oracle privilege for Create or Replace only one package

Tags: oracle, privileges

Is there any way that we set edit (create or replace)privilege for only one package ?
(suppose I have 10 package in my schema and need that other users could develop only one specific package in my schema )

Comment: That would basically allow your other users to inherit any privilege they desired from the package owner. A definitely bad idea in terms of security.

Comment: To alter stored procedures in another schema you must either have the "alter any procedure" privilege that allows updates to any procedure in the entire instance, or the user must have proxy privileges to become the procedure's owner and be able to alter anything in the schema. Alter privileges do not apply on an individual object level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can add this oracle privileges to make this situation :

```
grant execute any procedure to user;

grant debug any procedure to user;

grant debug connect session to user;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.

If you try it:

```
SQL> grant alter on pkg_test to mike;
grant alter on pkg_test to mike
               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02225: only EXECUTE and DEBUG privileges are valid for procedures


SQL>
```

Comment: thank you, but I used wrong Word, my purpose of "ALTER" was "Create or Replace"

Comment: That won't work either. System privilege named CREATE ANY PROCEDURE affects *all objects*, not a single one (it enables users to create a PL/SQL procedure, function or package owned by any user in the database.). Another one is ALTER ANY PROCEDURE, but - similarly - allows users who are granted that privilege to alter any procedure owned by any other user. So - shortly - **no, you can't do what you want**.